# To pass parameter from server side to client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code I have a dropdown in this I call js function from server side and I want to pass parameter to js function. In my case parameter is not passing. Please help me to solve this issue.

codebehind:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", "<script type=text/javascript> AddItem(" + EnumRows + ");</script>", true);
```

js:

```
function AddItem(EnumRows) {    
    // Create an Option object                
    // var opt = document.createElement("option");
    alert('this');
    // Add an Option object to Drop Down/List Box
    document.getElementById("<%=cbField.ClientID%>").options.add(opt);
    // Assign text and value to Option object
    opt.text = Value;
}
```

Comment: Not that I don't like js, but why don't you just add the item to the dropdownlist from the code-behind? Is there a specific reason you need to add via js... especially since it appears your dropdownlist is a server control?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev  i have a datarow i like to bind it in dropdownlist using javascript .

Comment: Yes but you can build/bind the dropdownlist [from the code-behind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dzka5sf(v=vs.85).aspx) and skip the javascript. Much cleaner, and more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", "AddItem('" + EnumRows + "');", true);
```

Comment: How to convert EnumRows to string when passing parameter

Comment: @user3319384 it is passing as string parameter (with single quotes),Anyway you can use the `Convert.ToString(EnumRows)` to convert it into string.

Comment: I tried but i got a alert msg like system.data.data[].How is it possible to bind the datarow to dropdown

Comment: Please post your code what you are doing. We don't what is `EnumRows` here?

Comment: This is a property  public DataRow[] EnumRows { get; set; } it has values i want to pass as parameter to js

Comment: In that case you need to iterate the loop over this value and the pass the actual value (which is inside the DataRow) to the javascript function. But I would say if possible then bind the dropdown from server side instead of doing from client side.

Answer (score 0):

Below will help you

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", "AddItem(" + EnumRows + ");", true);
```

Comment: Adding a little commentary about how and why it works won't harm and make your answers much more valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use escape_javascript method on your parameter.

```
<%= escape_javascript(your_parameter) %>
```